# I want to create a voice assistant for my website in html?

Tags: html, forms, web, input

I want to create a website for blind people. I'm trying to design a voice-command feature on the site, eg. the website would request that a user enter their username, the user would say, "Abc," and then "Abc" would be typed into the form. Any advice?

Comment: This is far too broad a question for Stackoverflow (and people who can't use a website visually tend to have text-to-speech and/or text-to-braille software and hardware already so you should be learning how to support assistive technologies instead of replacing them).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do this. Blind people have Software to do this. eg. Jaws on PC or VoiceOver on iPhone.

But what you can do, to make your website more accesible for blind people is that you use the "alt" key in Pictures (only one example what you can do)

Here is a link that could help you:
https://fuzzymath.com/blog/improve-accessibility-for-visually-impaired-users/

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/make-website-more-accessible/347450/

There are websites out there, that can check your html code for accesibility. Just Google them you probably find one or two.

But there are not only blind people that have trouble with some websites, other People with different disabilities could have trouble with your website too.

I have a Visual Disability and I know some blind People, and me and the blind People I know are Programmers, soo yeah :D.

Comment: I agree with you, i have choose this topic for my final year project, thats why.. it is necessary to create this website

Comment: I am in my final year too. I am from Germany, so I could  change my project at this Date. I dont know about you, but maybe you can change your project to something else? Because your Project Idea is not useful in any way.

Comment: your don't have idea about my project, i also convert website in to application simply.. and about project i know what is its advantages..

Comment: Yeah but if you convert the Website into a Application, the Voice Assistant is still useless and makes things for blind people just more difficult. But if you really have to do it, I would suggest you, to use some scripting language and use technology, that already exists.

Comment: Finally i get the Android application about this topic , but problem is that this project is finally selected for my final year project, i can't change , it is necessary to create the website thats why i im asking query,,

Comment: Yeah, so simply Use Modern JavaScript Technology and librarys. Maybe there is a Library out there that can output text into voice.